# Web service method not hit when called via Objective C

Tags: ios, sql, json, web-services, post

My App_Code/IGetEmployees.vb file

```
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IGetEmployees
 <OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="json/contactoptions")> _
Function GetAllContactsMethod(strCustomerID As String) As List(Of NContactNames)
End Interface
```

My App_Code/GetEmployees.vb file

```
   <WebMethod()> _
 <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetAllContactsMethod(strCustomerID As String) As List(Of NContactNames) Implements IGetEmployees.GetAllContactsMethod
    Utilities.log("Hit get all contacts at 56")
    Dim intCustomerID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(strCustomerID)
    Dim lstContactNames As New List(Of NContactNames)
 'I add some contacts to the list.
Utilities.log("returning the lst count of " & lstContactNames.Count)
    Return lstContactNames
End Function
```

NContactNames is a class with 3 properties.
So i am using ASP.NET web services to retrieve information from SQL server and pass it to my iPad in JSON format. I have a problem with parameter passing. So like you see i have 2 files IGetEmployees.vb and GetEmployees.vb. I am implementing the method GetAllContactsMethod. What's happening is the two lines in GetEmployees.vb file (Utilities.log), they never get logged. The function is not getting called at all.

My objective c code to call this function

```
    NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"strCustomerID=%@",strCustomerID];
    jUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://xyz-dev.com/GetEmployees.svc/json/contactoptions"];
    jurl = [NSURL URLWithString:jUrlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:jurl];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@" request string is %@",[[request URL] absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"Done");

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(theConnection)
    {
        jData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSError *jError;
        NSMutableDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jData options:kNilOptions error:&jError];
        NSLog(@"%@",json); //Gets Here and prints (null)
        NSLog(@"Done"); //prints this as well.

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
```

At the time of posting this code the "if" statement is true and (null) is printed followed by "Done"
The output of my absolute request is:
    request string is http://xyz-dev.com/GetEmployees.svc/json/contactoptions
This is the first time i am writing json to accept parameters. So i might be missing something.What is it?Why is the function not getting called at all on the Visual Studio side. If you need more info please ask.Thanks...

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the output to be? You never even start the connection, much less get any data from it.

Comment: @warrenm. I add some values to my lstContactNames list. I did not put the code here, but actually on that method call a sql stored proc is fired and it returns 3/4 rows and i make 3/4 objects and add it to the list.I want to get those values in JSON format. Also what do you mean by "start the connection"?I saw an example on net and followed it.What is wrong here?

Comment: You should also try a rest client to ensure the server side is working correctly, then work on the iOS side and fix your NSURLConnection code.

Answer (score 0):

this is the moethod in Objetive-C, for that.

```
-(void) insertEmployeeMethod

{

    if(firstname.text.length && lastname.text.length && salary.text.length)

    {

        NSString *str = [BaseWcfUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertEmployee/%@/%@/%@",firstname.text,lastname.text,salary.text];

        NSURL *WcfSeviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setURL:WcfSeviceURL];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        // connect to the web

        NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        // NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:respData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSError *error;

        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 

                              JSONObjectWithData:respData 

                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 

                              error:&error];  



        NSNumber *isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber*)[json objectForKey:@"InsertEmployeeMethodResult"];


        //create some label field to display status
        status.text = (isSuccessNumber && [isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inserted %@, %@",firstname.text,lastname.text]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to insert %@, %@",firstname.text,lastname.text];
    }
}
```

Before to run the code, test your URL with POSTMAN, is an app from Google Chrome.
regards.