# Calling a asp.net webservice from objective c to return data in JSON format with parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, exception, parameters

```
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IGetEmployees
 <OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="json/contactoptions/?strCustomerID={strCustomerID}")> _
Function GetAllContactsMethod(strCustomerID As String) As List(Of NContactNames)
End Interface

   <WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetAllContactsMethod(strCustomerID As String) As List(Of NContactNames) Implements IGetEmployees.GetAllContactsMethod
Utilities.log("Hit get all contacts at 56")
Dim intCustomerID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(strCustomerID)
Dim lstContactNames As New List(Of NContactNames)
'I add some contacts to the list.
Utilities.log("returning the lst count of " & lstContactNames.Count)
Return lstContactNames
End Function
```

So when i write the above code and call it in the browser like this http://xyz-dev.com/GetEmployees.svc/json/contactoptions/?strCustomerID=123 i get 10 rows as results in JSON format. That is as i intended. But when i call from objective c side it throws exception like this

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

My objective c code is:

```
 NSString *strCustomerID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",123];
    jUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?strCustomerID=%@",@"https://xyz-dev.com/GetEmployees.svc/json/contactoptions/",strCustomerID];
NSLog(@"the jurlstring is %@",jUrlString);
    NSURL *jurl = [NSURL URLWithString:jUrlString];
NSError *jError;
    NSData *jData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jurl];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jData options:kNilOptions error:&jError];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    NSLog(@"Done");
```

Exception occurs at NSJSONSerialization line.
So this is sort of continuation to my question [Web service method not hit when called via Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130450/web-service-method-not-hit-when-called-via-objective-c.But) i changed my code little bit so I posted a new question. Is it the correct way i am writing the uritemplate on asp side?is it the right way i am calling on iOS side? Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks..

Comment: is the `jUrlString` correct?

Comment: please NSLog the url and check whether it is correct

Comment: @MidhunMP I changed my code above.I added the NSLog,and added '/' after contactoptions  and it outputs like this https://xyz-dev.com/GetEmployees.svc/json/contactoptions/?strCustomerID=123. I paste that in my browser and it outputs 10 records.

Comment: @Phanindar: is it the exact url ? I'm getting error on the above url !!!

Comment: @MidhunMP.Sorry. Its not.I have to replace the xyz with the client company name. But i wanted to say that the URL works and it gives me 10 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url does not seem to be correct.  make sure it is correct.

You need to follow the NSURLConnectionDelegate to setup this service.  Here is a some sample code I often reuse.  You need to setup your connection, then properly process your data.  I've created a delegate and notify on completion or error.

documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

ex.

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)


@implementation JSONService
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)start{
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *nsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?strCustomerID=%@",@"https://xyz-dev.com/GetEmployees.svc/json/contactoptions",strCustomerID]];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:nsURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            [self notifyDelegateOfError:error];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
        }

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
- (void)cancel{
    //TODO KILL THE SERVICE (GRACEFULLY!!!!!) -- ALLOW VC'S TO CANCEL THE SERVICE & PREVENT SEGFAULTS

}

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<WebServiceDelegate>)aDelegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setDelegate:aDelegate];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)processData:(NSData *)data{

    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    if(data == nil){
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"NO_DOMAIN" code:001 userInfo:nil];
        [self notifyDelegateOfError:error];
        return;
    }
    //EITHER NSDictionary = json or NSMutableArray = json
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                    options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];
    //NSArray *dataArray = [[json objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
    //... more parsing done here.

    //NO ERRORS ALL DONE!
    [self notifyDelegateOfCompletion];

}

- (void)notifyDelegateOfError:(NSError *)error{
    [delegate webService:self didFailWithError: error];
}


- (void)notifyDelegateOfCompletion
{   
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webServiceDidComplete:)]) {
        [delegate webServiceDidComplete:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Will do.  Most days I setup a similar form of the above code as a base class and subclass for each service I'm building, I usually only need to change parsing of data.

Comment: @propstm. Thanks. I have two questions.1.What type of delegate is the one you synthesized (line 3 of your code) and 2.what is <WebServiceDelegate>?

Comment: I have a sample web service project utilizing this concept on my github account.  Check it out and let me know if you're still having issues. https://github.com/propstm/SampleWeatherApp

Comment: @propstm.Thanks. The sample project helped me.

Comment: @propstm. I faced one issue though. I couldn't use dispatch_async. When i used dispatch_async the logic did not enter the block.I replaced async with sync and the code logic works as intended. Why is that happening?

Comment: That may be something I'd changed last night.  I realized that trying to, while in the async bloc, throw the error, you get an error.  you need to throw that error on the main thread for it to run w/o crashing.